# Installing matplotlib on windows

Tags: python, matplotlib

I need help to install matplotlib into my system. I want it to be installed into my virtual environment. But i cant seem to find good online sources for this. Are there any good sites for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can download `matplotlib` from [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/matplotlib/files/matplotlib). and a good tutorial on how to do it in windows can be found [here.](http://houndofweb.wordpress.com/2013/06/08/install-matplotlib-in-windows/)

The current stable version: [v1.3.1](http://sourceforge.net/projects/matplotlib/files/matplotlib/matplotlib-1.3.1/)

A release candidate for the next version: [1.4.0rc2](http://sourceforge.net/projects/matplotlib/files/matplotlib/matplotlib-1.4.0rc2/)

Comment: Why on earth do you link to v1.1.0 ?!

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend to use the anaconda bundle, everything you'll need is in there:
http://continuum.io/downloads